# Collective name for properties including expectation, variance, divergences, etc

Tags: probability, expected-value, terminology

Is there an established name for the class of properties of random variables such as expectation, variance, higher moments, divergences (e.g. divergence)?

These are properties of one or several random variables, that generally summarize the entire distribution rather than particular outcomes.  If we want to be more precise, we could say they are the class of functionals which map one or more random variables to a (generally  non-random) value.

I've been using the term *distributional properties* in my own writing, and *distributional operators* when taking the functional perspective.  But, I am wondering if there is a more established name.

Comment: Yes. Statistics :)

Comment: @Firebug That's the term for properties of *data.*  Also, some writers loosely (ab)use the word "parameter" for any distributional property, because parameters (of a distributional *family*) indeed are a kind of distributional property--but not all properties are valid parameters.

Comment: @whuber fair points